# Creating a Subsite with a folder structure inherting permissions from parent folders

Tags: permissions, template

My company got started with Sharepoint.

Our site is `/projects` with subsites under this like,

```
/projects/project1

/projects/project2

/projects/project3
```

In each project there are three folders,

```
Visitors

Construction

Managers
```

These sites are created using a template. But I have to set the permissions manually each time on every new Subsite we create.

Is there any way to make the folders inherit permissions from the parent site?
Like a group for Visitors, a group for Construction and a group for Managers?

Answer (score 0):

We can inherit the user permission from the site collection by site actions-> site permission. There you will find the inherit permission option in the top ribbon. 
It will inherit all the access permission from your base site.

But before that you must the access group like "Visitors", "Consatruc in your base site (site collection)
Then only it will inherit the permission levels.

Comment: Can I add different users to the group depending on the project? But maintaning the same groups?